# Contar registros agrupados en 3 tablas SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

soy nuevo en sql y tengo la siguiente duda.
Tengo una tabla llamada **preguntas**

[image: tabla preguntas]

Una tabla llamada **respuestas** (que contiene las respuestas admitidas para cada pregunta)

[image: tabla respuestas]

Y una tabla llamada **respondidas** (que contiene las respuestas realizadas por cada alumno a una pregunta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito lograr obtener es el total de cada respuesta de cada pregunta, algo como así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad lo que me falta es lograr que se vean las respuestas cuando no hayan respuestas de esa respuesta en una pregunta, cuando sea 0, como se ve en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que las demás logré obtenerlas con la siguiente sentencia sql

```
FROM preguntas,respondidas,respuestas
WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta=respondidas.id_pregunta 
AND respuestas.id_respuesta=respondidas.id_respuesta 
GROUP BY titulo_pregunta, contenido_respuesta
```

que me da el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen dos problemas en tu código, uno directamente relacionado con tu pregunta y otro más bien relacionado con la estructura de tu base de datos.

Empecemos con el problema de la estructura de la BD, pues empezar por ello nos servirá para lo que viene. Las tablas que nos importan en este caso son *respuestas* y *respondidas*, donde la primera establece mediante el campo *id_pregunta* que cada respuesta puede estar asociada a una sola pregunta, lo cual está perfecto hasta que introducimos *respuestas* a la ecuación.

En la tabla *respuestas* tenemos *id_respuesta* lo cual nos permite enlazar las respuestas del usuario con alguna de las opciones, más además incluimos *id_pregunta*, repitiendo información que ya podemos obtener de manera indirecta mediante el campo *id_respuesta*, puesto que, como dijimos antes, cada respuesta se asocia unicamente a una pregunta. Repetir dicho campo no hace más que introducir redundancia innecesaria, aumentando el riesgo de inconsistencia de datos en un futuro.

Eliminando dicho campo podemos lograr el mismo resultado que teníamos antes cambiando ligeramente la sentencia WHERE a lo siguiente:

```
WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta=respuestas.id_pregunta 
AND respuestas.id_respuesta=respondidas.id_respuesta
```

Siguiente con la sentencia WHERE, resulta que esta forma parte del problema por el cual surge tu pregunta. Concretamente, dicha sentencia es demasiado estricta para nuestros fines actuales.

Tomemos en cuenta la siguiente expresión:

```
respuestas.id_respuesta=respondidas.id_respuesta
```

Mientras que tu problema requiere que se tomen en cuenta todas las posibles respuestas, la expresión anterior, usada junto con WHERE, hará que solo se muestren aquellas respuestas que ya existan en *respondidas*. Esto se puede ver claramente si quitamos de tu sentencia de ejemplo los GROUP BY.

Si ejecutamos lo siguiente:

```
SELECT titulo_pregunta, contenido_respuesta
FROM preguntas,respondidas,respuestas
WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta=respuestas.id_pregunta 
AND respuestas.id_respuesta=respondidas.id_respuesta
```

La respuesta que obtengamos será similar a:

[image: SELECT sin GROUP BY]

Nótese que la respuesta "no" está completamente ausente de nuestro resultado. No podremos hacer que figure en nuestro conteo mientras esto siga así.

Para solucionarlo, vamos a mover nuestra condición para mostrar desde la sentencia WHERE directamente hasta un JOIN. ¿Para qué? Te preguntaras... Bueno, recordemos que nuestro problema principal es querer mostrar respuestas aunque no hayan sido respondidas ninguna vez. Al usar JOIN's, podemos decir cosas como "obtén las conciencias entre estas dos tablas, pero muestra todos los valores de la primera aunque no coincida con la segunda".

Si uso "tablaA LEFT JOIN tablaB ON condicion" podré ver todos los elementos de *tablaA* aunque no tengan coincidencia con la *tablaB* bajo mi *condicion*, de la misma forma que usando "RIGHT JOIN" podría ver todo lo de la *tablaB* aunque no tenga coincidencia con la *tablaA*.

Aterrizando en tu ejemplo concreto, nuestro SQL cambiará a

```
SELECT titulo_pregunta, contenido_respuesta
FROM preguntas,
respuestas LEFT JOIN respondidas
ON respuestas.id_respuesta=respondidas.id_respuesta 
WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta=respuestas.id_pregunta;
```

Y con ello finalmente lograremos el siguiente resultado:

[image: SELECT con Join]

Nótese que finalmente aparece la respuesta "no", a pesar de que nadie haya contestado con dicha respuesta aún. Para ver mejor lo que está pasando aquí, añadamos algunos campos al SELECT como id_respondida y respondidas.id_respuesta.

[image: Datos null tras SELECT]

Ahora al ver la fila en que aparece "no" también podremos ver los estragos del LEFT JOIN. Mientras que todas las respuestas que ya han sido respondidas al menos una vez tienen valores para *id_respondida* e *id_respuesta*, nuestro "no" carece de tales valores. Un LEFT JOIN funciona similar al WHERE cuando los campos de dos tablas tienen coincidencia, pero cuando dicha coincidencia no existe aún así entrega en el resultado todos los valores de la tabla de su izquierda sin los valores correspondientes de la tabla de la derecha. Es por eso que *id_respondida* e *respondidas.id_respuesta* continenen null.

Ya para terminar, tenemos que regresar el GROUP BY junto con el count, no sin antes corregir un último detalle. Si usamos count(*) se tomarán en cuenta todas las filas a pesar de que parte de sus valores sean nulos, lo cual causará que la cuenta de "no" sea 1.

[image: Count tras usar LEFT JOIN]

En realidad nos interesa contar por un campo de la tabla *respondidas* dado que queremos saber cuantas veces ha sido respondida cada opción de *respuestas*. Cualquier campo sirve, pero para el ejemplo usaré *id_respondida*.

El SQL final sería:

```
SELECT titulo_pregunta, contenido_respuesta,  count(id_respondida) as veces_respondida
FROM preguntas,
respuestas
LEFT JOIN respondidas ON respuestas.id_respuesta=respondidas.id_respuesta 
WHERE
 preguntas.id_pregunta=respuestas.id_pregunta
GROUP BY titulo_pregunta, contenido_respuesta
```

El cual nos arrojaría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias! quedé pero clarísimo con la respuesta, se agradece la dedicación!

Comment: @UnknDown De nada, aunque como recomendación para este tipo de preguntas recomendaría añadir un SQL básico para crear las tablas en cuestión y algunos de sus datos para hacer pruebas al final de tu pregunta, de modo que podamos responder más rápido. Pude haber respondido solo con la teoría pero no es mi estilo, así que me tomé mi tiempo de recrear las tablas para poder mostrar los resultados reales. No obstante como sabia que eso me llevaría tiempo, aplacé el responder tu pregunta hasta la noche cuando estuviera del todo libre.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, tienes razón, la próxima publicare el SQL de la base de datos, gracias de nuevo!